# I want to insert an array of type array into postgress but I don't know how to do it from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, postgresql

```
 query.callfunction('fn_create_mp_product', parameters, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            callback(err);
        } else {
            if (result.status == 'success') {
                callback(null, result);
            } else {
                callback(result.message);
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to pass the parameters to fn_create_mp_product function
in that parameter one on the perameter is an array of type array i want to insert it from node

```
  var products='array['+data.productId+']';
```

so i tried like this but it is hitting an error

```
{ error: function fn_create_mp_product(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (/home/alignminds/Desktop/insidersBackendgit/insiderbackend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/alignminds/Desktop/insidersBackendgit/insiderbackend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/alignminds/Desktop/insidersBackendgit/insiderbackend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 249,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42883',
  detail: undefined,
  hint:
   'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
  position: '15',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_func.c',
```

I just want   `array[23,23]` in this format parameter to pass on to my fuction what can I do

Comment: You can't insert an array. PostgreSQL doesn't know how to store a JavaScript array. But you can store the string `JSON.stringify([23,23])`. Remember to parse it with `JSON.parse` later.

Comment: read again the message `error: function fn_create_mp_product(....) does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear from your question if you want to pass a variable number of parameters to a Postgres function as an array or if one (or more) of the parameters that you pass to the function is an array of variable length.

The first scenery is not possible: Postgres function parameters are very strict, they are declared once and for all at function creation.

The second is possible. Let's say you have this table

```sql
create table tbl  (
    arr_col integer[] null
)
```

and this function that inserts values in the table

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.inserter(arr_value int[])
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
    insert into tbl (arr_col)
    select arr_value;
$function$
;
```

then you can use the function like this

```sql
select * from inserter(array[1,2])
```

The array inserted could have whatever length but it must have only one dimension (e.g. not a matrix), that's because from table creation the dimension cannot change.